How to develop excel/PowerPoint ContentApp add-in
I am trying to create a new content add-in for Excel/PowerPoint, and looking for resources that can help me figure out how to do this.
Here is what I have found so far
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/powerpoint-quickstart-content (Visual Studio)
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Content-Add-in-Humongous-Insurance (uses Visual Studio)
I have found a couple of other posts here (stackoverflow), but I havent been able to get past just the manifest.
I have my manifest setup correctly - my buttons show up in the ribbon, etc.
But I cannot find any information on how to actually get my content to insert - what commands do we use? Do I need to wrap our web content in someway to display on the slide/worksheet?
Or can Content addins only be create via Visual Studio? (since that is what the two samples I have seen are using)

A Content Add-in is automatically inserted as soon as the add-in is installed or sideloaded. You don't have to take any other action.
You mention "my buttons show up in the ribbon". This indicates that something has gone wrong. It is not possible to have custom ribbon buttons in a content add-in. The manifest schema for content add-ins, does support add-in commands. If you have custom ribbon buttons and they are showing up on the ribbon, then the type attribute of the <OfficeApp> must not be ContentApp. (Or else you are seeing buttons left over from some other add-in under development.)

I guess I misunderstood how content add-ins work then. I thought I would still need a button to insert the content

You not only don't need a button, there's no way to create one if the type attribute of the <OfficeApp> is ContentApp.
